# AppleScript - relinking file in Indesign - Cannot create the link resource from the given URI

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign, automator

I am trying to make a Folder action in Automator, which duplicates specific .indd file, opens it in InDesign and then relinks "test1.png" with a file that was dropped in the folder, which is bound to the Automator action.

I can get it working with hardcoded file path, but if I try getting the file path dynamically it gives me error "Cannot create the link resource from the given URI"

It's probably something very simple, but I am new to AppleScript and can't figure it out.

Code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "Finder"
    set filename to name of file input
end tell

tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
    if document 1 exists then
        tell document 1
            relink link "test1.png" to "Macintosh HD" & filename
            
            try
                update link "test1.png"
            end try
            
        end tell
    end if
end tell

return input
```

end run

Comment: I know next to nothing about Applescript. Just a guess: try to change `set filename to name of file input` with `set filename to POSIX path of file input` and `relink link "test1.png" to "Macintosh HD" & filename` with `relink link "test1.png" to filename`

Comment: @YuriKhristich thank you, unfortunately it still gives the same error :( I'm thinking it might be something to do with the file path having / between directories. If I am hardcoding the path the directories have to be separated with : instead of usual / for some reason. Such as relink link `"test1.png" to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:dusansadlon:Documents:IddTest2:RO-Christmas-2020-FB_Cover.png"`

Comment: if there will be just `path` instead of `POSIX path`?

Comment: @YuriKhristich  without POSIX it fails on the Finder part with error: Finder got an error: Can’t get path of document file…

Comment: Sad day. As a last resort, as far as I can tell, it's possible to run jsx script from Applescript. But I think that might be overkill.

Comment: I don't know what form the relink command is expecting but `input` provides the file reference for the dropped file. You can see what the text of it is by having the line `display dialog input as text` in your script. Note that if you remove the 'as text' then you will get an 'alias' file reference, which looks like what ID requires (i.e. like in the second comment). If it matches your file's path and name, try `relink link "test1.png" to input`.

Comment: @Mockman thank you. I have tried this and it gives error: Expected alias or string or string but received (/Users/dusansadlon/Documents/IddTest2/RO-Christmas-2020-FB_Cover.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Adobe InDesign to be able to test this but try this.

```
on run {input, parameters}

set theFile to input's item 1

tell application "Adobe InDesign 2020"
    if document 1 exists then
        tell document 1
            relink link "test1.png" to theFile
            try
                update link "test1.png"
            end try
        end tell
    end if
end tell

end run
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code actually gave me an error that "test1.png" doesn't understand the "relink" message. But with a slight change to your code it is now working and I am adding the working code as edit to your answer so others can see it.